# make an object's z axis parallel with another object's normals

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, transforms

I have a ball that's rolling around in a bowl, randomly, using rigid body physics with the rigid body motor constraint motor on the ball making it roll around.  I've put a cap on the ball by duplicating the ball and scaling it up, cutting off the bottom, and adding a Solidify modifier.  The cap stays on the ball using the Copy Location constraint.

The cap's local Z axis is always parallel to the world's Z axis.  How can I make it parallel to the bowl's normals for when the ball rolls up the side of the bowl?

Keeping the Copy Location constraint isn't necessary; it's what works for me.

Comment: Why don´t you just parent the cap to the ball? I don´t see any problems with that...

Comment: @Dino Binghou Xue because the ball is rotating, and when you do that the cap rotates as well.